# Dynamic Checkbox.Checked if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, checkbox

Below is my code, the code creates a new CheckBox for each HyperLink, it then names each CheckBox with the name of the Hyperlink. I then have an IF statement which checks whether the dynamically created CheckBox has been checked. If it has, display the name of the CheckBox in a label.

However.. the label is not populating. I have tested everything and the label gets populated if i do it manually. The label has saved view state aswell. Any ideas? :)

```
foreach (HyperLink folder in folderList)
            {
                CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();
                checkbox.Text = folder.Text.ToString();
                folder.Controls.Add(check);
                checkbox.EnableViewState = true;
                checkbox.AutoPostBack = true;    

                if(check.Checked)
                {
                    selectedFolder.Text = check.Text.ToString();
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you are not leaving any time for the checkbox to be checked (user input). You should use an event handler or something similar to capture the event that a checkbox is checked.

Also, I don't see "check" being defined anywhere.. Do you mean "checkbox" instead of "check"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes i changed check to checkbox for the sake of easier reading. You say add an event hander. I tried this with check.CheckedChanged += checkCheckBox(); However a. i was not able to pass my label as an argument. Also when creating a generic event handler passing (sender, e) I was not able to get that working either. Like you say i dont think there is a time to check user input. What would an event handler look like in this situation which gives time for user input? Thanks again

Comment: This might be in another question for someone more qualified to answer :). But I suspect that you are going in the right direction with the (sender,e) approach. The information you need should be retrievable from sender. Just play around with it till it works..

Comment: Ok thanks again, im struggling to reference my asp:Label though in the event handler as all this is in a class which inherits my default web form :/ Any ideas?

Comment: Probably you should only have 1 label, and keep adding the names of the checked checkboxes into that label. Like this: selectedFolder.Text += check.Text.ToString();

Comment: I only have 1 label, im struggling to reference that label as an argument in an event handler :/

Comment: Ive sorted it with 'checkBox.CheckedChanged += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    { Check_Changed(sender, e, selectedFolder); };' and then                                              private void Check_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e, Label selectedFolder)
            {
                CheckBox check = sender as CheckBox;
                selectedFolder.Text = check.Text.ToString();
            }

Comment: What do you mean? Did you give a name/ID to that label? If so it should be accessible to the event handler..